# Where does this symlink point to?

Tags: virtualization, symlink

The weirdest thing.

```
$ ls -al                                        ~/vm/win_8_1.pvm/Windows Disks 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 zoo  staff  102 Nov 22 14:04 .
drwx--x--x@ 15 zoo  staff  510 Nov 22 16:57 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 zoo  staff   10 Nov 22 14:04 C -> /Volumes/C
$ readlink C                                    ~/vm/win_8_1.pvm/Windows Disks 
/Volumes/C
$ ls -al /Volumes                               ~/vm/win_8_1.pvm/Windows Disks 
total 8
drwxrwxrwt@  3 root  admin   102 Nov 22 14:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  29 root  wheel  1054 Nov  2 15:07 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     1 Nov 22 12:49 MacSSD -> /
$                                               ~/vm/win_8_1.pvm/Windows Disks
```

Where the heck is `~/vm/win_8_1.pvm/Windows Disks/C` pointing to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pointing to the mounted system volume C (visible on the desktop see below) of your virtual Windows 8.1 machine. If you shut down the VM or disable `Share Windows` afterwards, the link still resides there.

[image: C]

To make C visible again and your Mac secure (Windows mustn't screw the Mac volume) adjust the settings like in the picture below:

[image: settings]

Comment: I don't see it on my desktop - and why can't I find it on my file system

Comment: comment to edit: it is not on my desktop. Double clicking the item in Finder yields "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “C” can’t be found"

Comment: then your vm is not running or you disabled `Windows Sharing` in the preferences afterwards

Comment: You seem knowledgeable enough about Parallels. What I'm _trying_ to do is to do a 1-way isolation of my guest OS. i.e. I don't want Windows screwing with my filesystem on my Mac. In order to restrict the visibility of the guest OS, I was forced to enable a security isolation setting. I'm not knowledgeable about filesystems... but I _should_ still be able to view the windows files from my Mac, no?

Comment: you may safely delete the folder `Windows Disks`and the link.

Comment: it's safe to mount C so configure the VM Options->Sharing->Mac Sharing off & Windows Sharing On (added a picture in the answer)

Comment: doh! this was much easier than what I did. Thanks so much for you time! Very much apprecited!

Comment: just delete/disable any folder in `Share Mac` -> `Custom Folder` (see above pic) then you may not access the Mac volume from within Windows